# I am getting cant not find module error on node.js

Tags: node.js

I am running nodemon index.js file via cmd.
Then I am getting Error: Cannot find module 'undefined/package.json'

I have installed all the modules and dependencies written in package.json file.

my Package.json file is -

```
{
  "name": "whasq-api",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "whasq-api",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.11.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "standard --fix",
    "test": "exit 0"
  },
  "author": "WhASQ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@rduk/configuration": "^2.2.3",
    "@rduk/errors": "^1.3.1",
    "@rduk/logger": "^1.0.3",
    "@rduk/logger-winston-loggly-factory": "0.1.0",
    "@rduk/logger-winston-provider": "^1.0.4",
    "@rduk/message-broker": "^2.4.0",
    "@rduk/provider": "^3.1.3",
    "@rduk/tasks-orchestrator": "^0.1.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.256.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "csv": "^3.1.0",
    "dotenv": "5.0.1",
    "elasticsearch": "^14.2.2",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "express-request-id": "^1.4.1",
    "helmet": "^3.15.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.2.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "orm": "^4.0.2",
    "pg": "^7.4.1",
    "react-s3-uploader": "^4.8.0",
    "socket.io": "2.0.4",
    "socketio-jwt": "4.5.0",
    "standard": "11.0.1",
    "swagger-express-mw": "0.7.0",
    "winston": "2.4.0"
  }
}
```

and my index.js file is -

```
'use strict'

const SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw')
const app = require('express')()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const jwt = require('socketio-jwt')
const middlewares = require('./lib/middlewares')

const logger = require('@rduk/logger')
const configuration = require('@rduk/configuration').load()
// const broker = require('@rduk/message-broker')

const serverSettings = configuration.settings.get('server')
const config = {
  appRoot: __dirname, // required config
  swaggerSecurityHandlers: {
    Auth: require('./lib/middlewares/auth')
  }
}

// process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AKIAJQNQTBQGBVMOAHCA';
// process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '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';
// app.use('/s3', require('react-s3-uploader/s3router')({
//     bucket: "whasq.com-dev",
//     region: 'eu-west-3', //optional
//     signatureVersion: 'v4', //optional (use for some amazon regions: frankfurt and others)
//     headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}, // optional
//     ACL: 'private', // this is default
//     uniquePrefix: true // (4.0.2 and above) default is true, setting the attribute to false preserves the original filename in S3
// }));

SwaggerExpress.create(config, (err, swaggerExpress) => {
  if (err) { throw err }

  middlewares.addTo(app)
  swaggerExpress.register(app)
})

server.listen(serverSettings.port, () => {
  logger.info(`server listening on port ${serverSettings.port}`)
})

// socket.io
io.use(jwt.authorize({
  secret: serverSettings.secret,
  handshake: true
}))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  logger.info(`${socket.decoded_token.username} connected to caw`)
  socket.join(socket.decoded_token.id)
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.leave(socket.decoded_token.id)
    logger.info(`${socket.decoded_token.username} disconnected from caw`)
  })

  socket.on('message', action => {
    console.log(action)
  })
})

// consume notifications queue
// broker.consume('notifications', io)
```

How to resolve this problem Error: Cannot find module 'undefined/package.json'

Comment: If your projects package file `Package.json` or `package.json`? and is it at the root of the project? IE not a sub-directory inside the project?

Comment: You should hide your S3 credentials btw